# How to process each value from structured streaming with kafka as a source?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I have problem statement to solve. I have a kafka producer which produces messages(xmls) to a particular topic. Now,this is a streaming data and I am using spark streaming to get those messages from the topic. I am writing those messages to console output. Now, there is an operation that needs to be done on those messages(they are xmls basically), those xmls needs to be parsed and I have written parser for it too. Now, when I use xml as hardcoded into a string variable  the parser is working fine. But, I need to get the xmls from spark dataframe. This is what I have done so far for getting messages from kafka.

```
  val spark = SparkSession.builder
  .appName("kafka-ingestion")
  .master("local")
  .config("spark.sql.orc.impl","native")
  .getOrCreate()

 import spark.implicits._

 // Gets the xpath
 //val xpaths = get_xpaths(filename)
 val df = spark
   .readStream
   .format("kafka")
   .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
   .option("subscribe", "xmlpoc")
   .option("encoding","UTF-8")
   .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
   .load()

val df2 = df.selectExpr( "CAST(value AS STRING)")

df2.writeStream.format("console")
  .outputMode("append")
  .start().awaitTermination()

// Now perform parsing on each value of df2.
```

When I do this, I can see all the messages in a dataframe to the console. But, I wish to perform an operation to all those messages(like parsing here). I have no idea how to do that. i tried udfs, but they add another column besides my value column. So, nothing seems to be working. Any help appreciated.

Comment: What's wrong with adding other columns? If you also drop the source column at the end of the parsing, then it should work as expected. Also, JSON would likely be easier to parse than xml within Spark

Comment: @cricket_007 I am bound to use xmls as the format for incoming messages as they are something the client is producing and we are asked to consume and parse it. Do  you see any other way/best way to achieve the same  ?  If I somehow being able to consume the messages in string format in a variable, one by one, my task is almost done. Is there any way ?

Comment: Not with Structured Streaming, no. You'd have to use Dstream for that